# python threading to download list of dictionaries

Tags: python, multithreading

I have a list of 1000 dictionary each dictionary contains url,file_name

```
for di in images_to_download:
    temp = download_image(di['img_url'],di['image_full_name'])
    if not temp:
        continue
    upload_file(temp,t4['id'])



def download_image(img_url,image_full_name)
    try:
        req = request(img_url, headers=headers)
        raw_img = urlopen(req).read()
        try:
            with open(image_full_name,'wb') as file:
                file.write(raw_img)
        except:
            image_full_name = query+str(random.randint(100000))
            with open(image_full_name,'wb') as file:
                file.write(raw_img)
        return image_full_name
    except Exception as e:
        print ("Download failed: {}".format(e))
        return None

def upload_file(file_name,folder_id):
    file2 = drive.CreateFile({'parents': [{'id': folder_id}]})
    file2.SetContentFile(file_name)
    file2.Upload()
```

This is my code so far it works well, but it is slow (3-6 sec per image), so I would like to thread it How can I do that?

The images are from different websites so I can download them without too fast requests on website.

Comment: The [`threading` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html) provides support for multi-threading.

Comment: @ForceBru How can I implement this in code please

Comment: Stack Overflow is _not_ a free code-writing service. We do _not_ write code for people, but we help them fix issues in their _existing_ code. If your code doesn't work, then a question about this code may suit this site. However, if there _is_ no code, and one would like someone to write it for them, we don't do that here.

Comment: @ForceBru I understand but I thought it would be an easy for loop for someone here ( I am new to programming). Also I mentioned in my question that my code works I just want to make it faster by using threading